# Why does a tangent bundle have dimension 2n instead of n?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $n=dim(T_pM)$ for every $p\in M$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold. I understand that specifying $p$ is not enough to determine an element of $TM$, but what if do we specify only $v\in T_pM\subset TM$? Since the tangent spaces are disjoint, specifying $v$ is all we need to determine the respective element of $TM$, which is $v$ itself. Therefore I don't understand why $dim(TM)=2n$.

PS: I know there are some related posts over here, but none of them have answered my question.

Comment: The bundle being dimension $2n$ includes both the dimension of $M$ itself as well as the dimension of the tangent space.

Comment: To specify a point in the bundle, you need both a point $p$ and a vector $v\in T_pM$. Just a vector, without a point to "pin" it to makes no sense.

Comment: Specifying that $v$ (i.e. specifying which of the disjoint tangent spaces we're looking at *and* where in the tangent space we are) requires $2n$ numbers, no matter how you do it.  If you don't give enough information to say what $p$ is, then you haven't specified an element of $TM$.

Comment: Specifying $v$ requires two pieces of information: the base point $p \in M$ which has $n$ degrees of freedom; and the choice of a vector in $T_p(M)$ which has $n$ independent degrees of freedom. Add those up and you get $n+n=2n$ degrees of freedom altogether.

Answer (score 6):

There are various definitions of the tangent space. A possible one is, for $p \in M$:
$$T_p M = \{ \gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M \mid \gamma(0) = p \} / \sim$$
where $\sim$ is, informally, the equivalence relation $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2 \iff \gamma_1'(0) = \gamma_2'(0)$ ($\gamma'(0)$ is not actually well defined, it is only defined if you choose a chart around $p$; but given two charts, the derivatives are equal in one iff they are equal in the other, so the equivalence relation is well-defined).

As a set, the tangent space $TM$ is then defined as the union of all the $T_pM$, i.e. $$TM = \bigcup_{p \in M} T_p M.$$

Using a chart, it's easy to see that if $M$ is an $n$-manifold, then $T_p M$ is a vector space of dimension $n$. And a tangent vector $v = [\gamma]$ does carry the information of which point $p$ it lies over, because $p = \gamma(0)$ (and this is independent of the representative of the equivalence class). There is no such thing as a "bare" tangent vector that would somehow be tangent to the manifold without specifying at which point it is tangent.<sup>*</sup>

But then why isn't $TM$ of dimension $n$ too? The thing is that there is a *ton* of vector spaces glued together to make up $TM$; in fact, one for each point of $M$. Just like $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is made up of a *ton* of vector spaces of dimension one glued together (e.g. the $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$) and has dimension two, we cannot expect $TM$ to only have dimension $n$.

Heuristically, as Lee Mosher explains in the comments, we have $n$ degrees of freedom to choose the point $p \in M$, then another $n$ degrees of freedom to choose a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$. So in total $TM$ should have dimension $2n$.

To make this precise, you first need to give a topology to $TM$; informally, $[\gamma_1]$ and $[\gamma_2]$ will be "close" if 1/ $\gamma_1(0)$ and $\gamma_2(0)$ are "close" in $M$ and if in a chart, $\gamma'_1(0)$ and $\gamma'_2(0)$ are close in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your differential topology textbook probably makes that precise. Then you need to cook up charts for $TM$, and in fact if $U \subset M$ is a chart $U \cong \mathbb{R}^n$, then $TU \subset TM$ will be homeomorphic to $U \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ $\gets$ this is where the dimension $2n$ appears! Then you need to check that the change of chart maps are smooth.

---

<sup>*</sup> I think a possible source of confusion on this comes from framed manifolds. If your manifold $M$ is framed, then you have a bundle isomorphism $\phi : TM \to M \times \mathbb{R}^n$. It's then tempting to think of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a tangent vector to $M$. This is perhaps what some people in this thread are calling a "bare" vector, or an "untagged" vector. But really, this $x$ is a (tangent) vector **field**, given by $$\xi_x(p) = \phi(p,x) \in TM.$$
So it is no surprise that this "tangent vector" seems to lie over no point in particular, because it's not a tangent vector: it's something that associates a tangent vector to each point (and in a smooth way). This is for example the case for $\partial/\partial x$, which is really a tangent vector *field* over $\mathbb{R}$ and not just a tangent vector.

In general manifolds aren't framed though, so this kind of confusion cannot arise. If you define carefully the tangent space, then you will see that a tangent vector does have the information of both a point of $M$ *and* some kind of tangent vector in a chart or something like that. That's $2n$ coordinates worth of information, hence $\dim TM = 2n$.

Answer (score 4):

If all you specify is $v$, you haven't picked a point in $TM$, you have (simultaneously) picked a point in each $T_pM$.  (Edit:  Assuming that point $v$ actually is in each $T_pM$.)  To pick a single point in $TM$, you need to pick a $p \in M$ and then a $v \in T_pM$ (or vice versa -- either way, two choices).

Example:  $T\Bbb{R} \cong \Bbb{R}^2$ and to pick a point in the plane takes two coordinates.  (This Cartesian product relation between $M$ and $TM$ is relatively uncommon, but is easy to see for Euclidean spaces.)

Edit: Further elaboration:  A $T_pM$ is a vector space.  It contains vectors.  It doesn't contain tagged vectors.  In particular, the elements of a $T_pM$ do not in any way indicate to which $p$ they are associated.  $TM$ is the disjoint union $\sqcup_{p \in M} T_pM$.  One standard set theoretic implementation of the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Set_theory_definition) is as the set of ordered pairs $(p, v)$ (the $p$s are the index of the disjoint union).  Since a given tangent vector may be in several such pairs, it is not enough to merely indicate the $v$.  You must indicate both $p$ and $v$ to pick a specific element of $TM$.

Comment: That's the thing, how can $v$ be in more than one tangent space? If we say $v\in T_pM$ we need only $n$ numbers to specify $v$ (the information that $v$ is based on $p$ is already in $v$ itself), then somehow when we embed the tangent space into the tangent bundle, saying now $v\in T_pM\subset TM$, we need $2n$. Why do we loose the information about the base point in this case?

Comment: @Mr.K : Which $T_p\Bbb{R}$ is $\partial/\partial x$ in?  Tangent vectors do not indicate their base points.

Comment: "the elements of a $T_p M$ do not in any way indicate to which $p$ they are associated": this depends on how you construct the tangent space, and in general they certainly do. $TM$ is a topological space, equipped with a projection $\pi : TM \to M$. How could that projection even be defined if an element of $TM$ didn't already have the information of which point it is lying over? But if say $M$ is parallelized, $TM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^n$, then no, a bare element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ doesn't define a tangent vector, as indeed an element of $TM$ is a pair $(x, v) \in M \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : An element of $TM$ is an element of a disjoint union.  Elements of disjoint unions are pairs, $(p,v) \in M \times T_pM$ and note that the space of the second element depends on the first element.  But the elements of $T_pM$ are just vectors, not tagged vectors, so a particular $v \in T_pM$ has no way of knowing that it is based at $p$ -- it's just a vector.  The *pair* $(p,v)$ can trivially be projected onto its first element, so there is a map from $TM \rightarrow M$, but there is no map $\pi_2(TM) \rightarrow M: v \mapsto p$ because $v$ has no information on $p$.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning... What's your (precise) definition of $T_pM$?

Comment: The definition of the tangent space in terms of germs leads to disjoint tangent spaces for different points on the manifold, so the tangent bundle is defined using the usual union, not the disjoint union. In this case, why can we look at the elements of $TM$ as ordered pairs $(p,v)$? I would say that $v$ is an element of $TM$ since it is an element of one of the tangent spaces. I think this is the source of my confusion.

Comment: @Mr.K : Then we're back to my question:  in which $T_p\Bbb{R}$ is $\partial/\partial x$?  Answer:  All of them.

Comment: @EricTowers It's in none of them, as it is a vector **field**, not a tangent vector... Have you read my answer?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : You realize calling it either "a vector field" or "a vector in every $T_pM$" is a distinction without a difference?  I have read your answer.  Other than using a union where I have only ever seen a disjoint union, there is essentially no difference with mine.

Comment: You mean apart from the conceptual mistake where you claim that somehow there exist "tangent vectors" that are not tangent at any particular point of the manifold, but you need to specify the point to make it a true vector? This is like claiming that a function on $M$ is a number, except that it depends on which point of $M$ you're looking at. Sure, you can think of it like that, but the word for it is "function", not "number". It is IMO misleading to claim that there can somehow be tangent vectors not lying over any particular point - as explained in my answer, that's wrong.